MIDAS regression - How can I choose lag k?
I'm a Ph.D student and I'm learning how to compute the MIDAS regression in R, but I wonder how to choose the k lags for the computaion, for example, of the "nealmon" MIDAS weights (or any other function as "nbeta", "nbetaMT", "polystep" etc).
Particurarly, in the author's documentation I see these commands:
fn_x <- nealmon(p = c(1, -0.5), d = 8)
fn_z <- nealmon(p = c(2, 0.5, -0.1), d = 17)
My questions are: How can I select the "p" in the previous commands? Are in the "midasr" R package some command that I can use to select this "p"?
I tried to calculate the parametrization (as in "Mixed Frequency Data Sampling Regression Models: The R Package midasr" by Ghysels et al. (2016)) but I can't find a pratical solution. Can anyone help me understand?
